# Give a NFA over the alphabet {a ,b , c}

Tags: automata, formal-languages

How do I solve this?

Give a NFA over the alphabet {a, b, c} whose words have a length which is multiple of 4 or are such that the number of a’a plus the number of b’s in the word is even.

Use then the subset construction to build the corresponding DFA.

I am unsure if the NFA will look like this

[image: i am unsure if the NFA will look like this]

or like this...

[image: or like this...]

and I know it has to be with a,b and c instead but how do I do that?

Comment: What do $0$ and $1$ stand for in the diagram? $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The automatons doesn't fit to the question, this automatons are over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Either structure is fine for the NFA, although you are missing some loops.  Conceptually I think the first one is much easier to read and you'll have fewer chances of making a mistake when working with it.  The only advantage to the second one is that it is epsilon-free so you may find it slightly easier to do the subset construction (but since there's only two initial epsilon arcs it makes no practical difference).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I think that it’s at least as easy to construct a DFA directly. Since every DFA is in fact an NFA as well, this does not violate the letter of the instructions, though it may violate their spirit.

Let $L_0$ be the set of words over $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ whose lengths are divisible by $4$, and let

$$L_1=\left\{w\in\Sigma^*:|w|_a+|w|_b\text{ is even}\right\}\;;$$

your language is $L=L_0\cup L_1$. Start by building a DFA $M_0$ for $L_0$; this is very easy and can be done with just $4$ states. Then build a DFA $M_1$ for $L_1$; this is also easy and can be done with just $2$ states. Then form the cross-product DFA $M$ of $M_0$ and $M_1$; if $Q_0$ and $Q_1$ are the state sets of $M_0$ and $M_1$, respectively, the state of $M$ is $Q_0\times Q_1$, and the transitions are set up so that

$$\langle p,q\rangle\overset{x}\longrightarrow\langle p',q'\rangle$$

is a transition of $M$ if and only if

$$p\overset{x}\longrightarrow p'$$

is a transition of $M_0$ and

$$q\overset{x}\longrightarrow q'$$

is a transition of $M_1$. This means that $M$ in effect runs $M_0$ on the first coordinate of the states and $M_1$ on the second coordinate. With a proper choice of initial state (for which there really is only one sensible choice, and it’s the right one) and acceptor states $M$ will accept $L$. By the way, by suitably changing the acceptor states you can make accept and of the languages $L_0\cap L_1$, $L_0\setminus L_1$, and $L_1\setminus L_0$ instead, so this is a very useful construction. You may find [this PDF](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ko/pdfs/lecture-3.pdf) helpful

Comment: but when i do the cross-product doesn't it become 'and' , i mean the question says:    words have a length which is multiple of 4 OR                 are such that the number of a’a plus the number of b’s in the word is even but now when we do the cross product it becomes AND instead of OR.. if you know what i mean...

Comment: @Paul: As I said in my answer, whether you get $L_0\cap L_1,L_0\cup L_1,L_0\setminus L_1$, or $L_1\setminus L_0$ depends entirely on which states you make acceptor states.

Comment: how do i know which are the acceptor states? is there a formula or a way to know how to find the acceptor states?

Comment: @Paul: If you understand how the product automaton works, you should have little trouble figuring out which states need to be acceptor states. You want $M$ to accept a word if at least one of $M_0$ and $M_1$ would accept it; that tells you exactly which states in $Q_0\times Q_1$ have to be acceptor states.

Comment: ok, i think i understand, to be more clearly do you have an example? so i can see how it is solved step by step...

Comment: @Paul: There is an example in the PDF to which I linked.

Comment: it's really more a definition, i was referring to a similar task that is like this one so i can se how they solve it..

Comment: @Paul: The sixth and seventh slides *are* an example.